# Why getUserMedia stopped working suddenly

Tags: javascript

I used to use this function to check the mic:

```js
function checkMicrophone() {
  console.log('checkMicrophone executed')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    }).then(stream => {
      console.log('res')
      resolve();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('err')
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

checkMicrophone()
```

And it was working till just today!

What happened it doesn't return the promise nor the err ?

Comment: This function works for me. Please provide more context. What browser are you using? How are you calling the function?

Comment: Chrome, Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)-------  Can you see `console.log('checkMicrophone res')` ?

Comment: I can, yes. If you're still encountering this issue, my bet is that you're not calling the function.

Comment: Open inspect element, and copy-paste your code into the console. Does it still not work?

Comment: Not working in chrome and in firefox I see the err log

Comment: Really weird. I have no idea. Have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: Try adding       console.log('err', err) inside the catch block and check result in Firefox this might help you realise the problem with Chrome